# Pass Image to other activity

Tags: android, image

I want to load image from web, then decode it by the BitmapFactory.decode() method.

now I have image in bitmap. i want it to load on the imageview which is View of the another activity

So how can i load the image on the other activity

Comment: why cant you send image url to another activity

Comment: I have to load on parent activity and then when it fully load then show it on child activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the application context to hold the bitmap.

Way to use app context.

Extend the application class and add a attribute of type Bitmap. So in your activity you can access the application context and get the bitmap. As the application context is a singleton it will be the same instance in every activity.

```
MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
appContext.bitmap = YOUR BITMAP;
```

In any other activity you can access that bitmap the same way.

```
MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
```

Now the bitmap is in the appContext object.

You also need to add

> android:name=".MyApplication"

to application tag in the manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap appears to inherit 'Parcelable'.  This implies you should be able to `putExtra()` and then `getParcelableExtra()`

Comment: The image must be too large.  There is a limit on the size of the parcelable.  Your better option then would be to store the image to a file and pass data to the intent on how to get it.

Comment: See this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/KKEyW6XdDvg/discussion

Comment: please can you give me some example to write a file locally and read it from other activity

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?aq=1&oq=android+write+file&gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+write+file+to+sd+card